# Ender Dragon characteristics

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How far can the Ender Dragon see?  Does it try and stay close to the re-charge towers (Ender Crystals)?

I am trying find out if I can build a Endermen EXP farm in the End while the dragon is still alive?

I have made a walk way to ~500 blocks away from the main landmass.  The dragon doesn't seem to follow me that far out, and doesn't seem to come out to get me, but can I assume this will always be the case?

Comment: The Ender Dragon will "get stuck" if you get to far away from him (meaning he will not follow you)

Comment: The farm thing is a bit of a silly idea... Because your going to have to kill yourself to leave the end, without use of an end portal, and lose all XP gained...

Comment: @Jonny, I will setup an Enchanting table at the farm, and an Enderchest to store the enchanted items in.

Comment: @Zoredache Ah Okay, still just seems easier with the portal in the long run, IMO.

Comment: The server I am playing right now, they don't want to kill the dragon for another couple weeks.  But I want fast enchanting right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go far enough from the island, the health bar for the dragon will disappear. It is safe to build at that place. See for example [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f2tL3KTVYo&t=517) at 08:30.

Once all players are outside a 320x320 square centered on the dragon, the server will stop updating the dragon entity (time stops for the dragon). Otherwise, the dragon can go practically anywhere in The End.

Comment: While this does confirm my question, that it seems to stay away, I was hoping for something more concrete.

Comment: @Zoredache I have included more concreteness in the answer now

Answer (score 2):

The Ender Dragon has some unusual characteristics. The Ender Dragon can spot a player practically anywhere in the Ender. However there are some set backs. Your mob spawner must be out of obsidian because the Ender Dragon can destroy any other material it comes in contact with. It will look like the TNT explosion. The Ender Dragon usually will hang around it's crystals for "Power and Food" but will swoop down on a player if the are within 30 blocks of a crystal. The Ender Dragon's flying radius is huge but it's hard for him to turn easily. He has to make large swooping motions, about a 40 block diameter for it to come around and attack again.

Answer (score 1):

The Ender Dragon characteristics I've seen are that he sees me no matter where I am at on his island and if I stay about 20 blocks from his towers he will only attack me by coming straight at me and trying to ram.  Only when I'm near the towers does he toss magic at me.  If I stay 20 blocks or so away and shoot at him as soon as I see him plowing through Endermen I can score 4 or 5 shots per ram attempt and he starts to turn around at the third shot I score.